# Python Discord Bot. Error 429 "is rate limited. Retrying in"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a bot that works with a state machine. Only on three users I get this error. I don't send many messages. They are looped, but there is a 3 second timeout between them. I can't figure out what's wrong. The code that generates the error (I think) is below.

discord.webhook.async_: Webhook ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is rate limited. Retrying in 0.30 seconds.

The error does not appear immediately, somewhere in a minute of simultaneous work of test users.

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, args=""):
  msm = StateMachine(ctx.author)

  while True:
      embeds, buttons_conf, button_timeout, is_exit = msm.current_data()
      if is_exit:
        break

      if embeds:
        for cur_embed in embeds:
          parameter_count = len(cur_embed)
          if parameter_count == 1:
            await ctx.send(embed=cur_embed[0], ephemeral=True)
          elif parameter_count == 2:
            await ctx.send(embed=cur_embed[0], file=cur_embed[1], ephemeral=True)
          elif parameter_count == 3:
            await ctx.send(embed=cur_embed[0], file=cur_embed[1], ephemeral=True)
             await asyncio.sleep(cur_embed[2])  # waiting

      if buttons_conf:
        view = ViewButtons(buttons_conf, ctx, timeout=button_timeout)
        view.message = await ctx.send(view=view, ephemeral=True)
        await view.wait()
        await view.disable_all_items()
        
        next_command = view.next_command()
        msm.set_last_button(next_command)

      msm.to_next_step()
```

With one user - the error never occurs (during the development of the functionality, everything worked well).
That's when I invited my friends to the test - such errors appeared.
I myself was able to reproduce this error with only three test users.

Comment: Where is the cooldown? `while True` is basically causing the error here.

Comment: The problem was that I was sending multiple messages in a row without a timeout. As soon as I combined these messages into one, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was sending multiple messages in a row without a timeout. As soon as I combined these messages into one, the problem disappeared.